# Cakephp 3 How create link to file outside of webroot and APP in video folder

Tags: php, video-streaming, cakephp-3.0, synology

If I place video file to for example

`www.myweb.com/webroot/video.mp4`

I am able to play it in VLC player in streaming option. I am using CakePHP 3 framework.
Where this file is placed in

**/volume1/web/myweb/webroot/video.mp4**.

But my question is how do I create link to file which is in Synology NAS, its link is:

**'/volume1/video/Films/video.mp4'**

To be accessible from a web?

I added to open_basedir in PHP in a directory :/volume1/video;

Comment: https://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?t=126518

Comment: Have you tried a symbolic link?

Comment: ok symbolic link. I added to .htaccess row: Options +FollowSymLinks. in SSH I added command:  ln -s "/volume1/video/Films/video.mp4" video.mp4  . Then I tried to access file like: www.myweb.com/webroot/video.mp4.  Such file doesnt exist. is response.

Comment: Can you access the file with the symbolic link from your shell? If you can't access the symbolic link from the shell, start by figuring that out. Also, do a symbolic link to the main folder, not to the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pointing to the actual file, have you tried reading the file using a PHP script?

For example, your site could have a link such as `yoursite.com/video.mp4`, but instead, you could have `yoursite.com/getfile.php?f=video.mp4`.

This `getfile.php` script can securely get the file from anywhere in your file server where your `www` user has access.

I personally use the `readfile_chunked` function documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) in the comments, as well as the appropriate headers needed to be sent before.

**Note**: Make sure you secure your `getfile.php` script to prevent users from reading *any* files on your drive. In my case, I force my script only to accept certain keys which correspond to actual files (ex: `yoursite.com/getfile.php?filekey=Ab183Fca82`, where `Ab183Fca82` points to `video.mp4`)

Comment: Thank you guys, I think solution on symlink in PHP works: `symlink('/volume1/video/Films/video.mp4','/volume1/web/myweb/webroot/video.mp4');`  I was inserting symlink first to different location.It must be in webroot. And sure I add there token behind the name of file.

Comment: Then other problem occured with symlink ownership.Because http ownership doesnt allow to play video in VLC.